# How could you implement something like Excel 2007's databars in HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, excel, user-interface

What I'd like to do is produce an HTML/CSS/JS version of the following.  The gridlines and other aspects are not important.  It's more of a question how to do the background databars.

[image]
<sub>(source: [tech-recipes.com](http://blogs.tech-recipes.com/shamanstears/files/2008/04/excel_databars2.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the bars as background images and position them to show values. eg. with a fixed column width of 100px:

```
<div style="background: url(bg.gif) -50px 0 no-repeat;">5</div>
<div style="background: url(bg.gif) -20px 0 no-repeat;">8</div>
```

If your columns have to be flexible size (not fixed, and not known at the time the page is produced), it's a bit trickier:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .cell { position: relative; }
    .cell .back { position: absolute; z-index: 1; background: url(bg.gif); }
    .cell .value { position: relative; z-index: 2; }
</style>

<div class="cell">
    <div class="back" style="width: 50%;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="value">5</div>
</div>
<div class="cell">
    <div class="back" style="width: 80%;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="value">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A javascript-based solution like this [cross-browser gradient](http://slayeroffice.com/code/gradient/) might be a good start.

With some DHTML, you can make a [bar with a given length](http://slayeroffice.com/code/gradientProgressBar/).

Answer (score 0):

I would use either the Grid component from [Ext JS](http://extjs.com/products/extjs/) library or the [DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) component Yahoo's YUI library. The cross-browser compatibility, etc. work is done for you.